# Cannot install Voyager - Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos

Tags: laravel, voyager

I have a problem I am not able to solve. I cannot install Voyager (windows 10/XAMPP/Laravel  8.20.1). I run the command `composer require tcg/voyager` in my project directory, but I keep getting the below error message:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
– Installing tcg/voyager (1.x-dev e9160b7): Cloning e9160b7c10
Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+DESKTOP-8VORIAK+2020-12-31+1216
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in “C:/Users/Diana/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json” for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden): Install of tcg/voyager failed

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

[ErrorException]
copy(phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/../Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe): failed to open
stream: phar error: “vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe” is not a file in phar “C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer
.phar”
```

I follow the github link but all I'm presented with is the ability to generate a new personal access token with no instructions on what to do with it.

Would appreciate some thoughts on how to solve this issue.

Thanks

UPDATE: Should use personal token instead of password when performing Git operations over HTTPS. Thanks @Muhammad Anas

Comment: could you show your composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can read this documentation of how to create the personal access toke. And how to use this in terminal](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

You can ignore this warning as tcg/voyager is not a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I used a random personal access token without any scopes then it works.
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DQYB.png)